# Apps that were active won't launch after crash

Tags: macos, crash, reboot

im having a really strange problem here.  My macbook air running mountain lion locked on me so i held the power button down to restart it.  When it restarted, the OS offered to reopen the apps I had running.  I declined.  Now I cannot run any of those apps.  Even reinstalling the apps didn't help.  I can still run apps that weren't running at the time of the crash.

Thank you very much for the help!

## BBEDIT

```
Process:         BBEdit [2636]
Path:            /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit
Identifier:      com.barebones.bbedit
Version:         10.5.2 (3264)
App Item ID:     404009241
App External ID: 13641604
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [260]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-03-12 11:11:26.219 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          1301 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           137
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1001440 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   3
Anonymous UUID:                      79A755BF-CD40-3FAA-AD9C-722A60F522FE

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

VM Regions Near 0xc594:
    __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit
--> __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000696000 [ 6740K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit
    __DATA                 0000000000696000-0000000000714000 [  504K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x92964b47 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 0
1   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927eb980 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 430
2   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927eb7ca SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 94
3   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927e6729 HIObject::Create(__CFString const*, OpaqueEventRef*, HIObject**) + 309
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927e65da HIObjectCreate + 96
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927e644e HIApplication::GetApplication() + 54
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927e6402 GetApplicationEventTarget + 11
7   com.barebones.bbedit            0x0000426c CApplication::CApplication() + 524
8   com.barebones.bbedit            0x00004004 MakeApplication() + 36
9   com.barebones.bbedit            0x001836f6 main + 452
10  com.barebones.bbedit            0x000031e5 start + 53

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x934a80ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9307a04c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93079e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93061cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x934a89ae kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9a14fc71 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 993
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x9a14f7a9 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x934a80ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9307a04c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93079e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93061cca start_wqthread + 30
```

### Google chrome

```
Process:         Google Chrome [2573]
Path:            /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:      com.google.Chrome
Version:         25.0.1364.160 (1364.160)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [260]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-03-12 11:08:11.845 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          1107 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           116
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  4 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   6
Anonymous UUID:                      79A755BF-CD40-3FAA-AD9C-722A60F522FE

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

VM Regions Near 0xc594:
    __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
--> VM_ALLOCATE            0000000000001000-0000000000018000 [   92K] ---/--- SM=NUL  
    __TEXT                 0000000000018000-0000000000019000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x92964b47 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 0
1   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927eb980 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 430
2   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927eb7ca SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 94
3   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x927e6729 HIObject::Create(__CFString const*, OpaqueEventRef*, HIObject**) + 309
4   c
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Saved Application State folder?

Comment: I did clear that folder out, but its still crashing.  I've read about permission issues on folders after crashes that can cause this as well.

Comment: Have you repaired your disk using Disk Utility? Try fixing permissions as well - that may help

Answer (score 1):

You've done most of the fault isolation by reinstalling the applications. Furthermore, the odds that your two apps are both causing problems is a very low likelihood, so you could do two more quick steps to make sure it's not an easy fix.

- Make a new user account, turn off automatic user log in at boot, and log out of your current account. Log in to the new account and test the two crashing apps. If they don't crash, you've **isolated the problem to your user account data, state and preferences**.
- Shut down the Mac and start up in Safe Mode. Log in to the new account, test the apps. Log out and log in to your normal account (still in safe mode) and test the apps.

Safe Mode will let you know if third party or optional Apple software is conflicting with the apps.

At this point, you'll have narrowed down three new situations that you didn't cover and have a very good idea if you need to reinstall the OS or just clear things systematically from your user account (or back up files and then restore your user account settings and preferences from a backup before the crashes started).

Once you've cornered the issue - you'll have a better feeling for how to fix things and get back to using apps rather than troubleshooting them.